# Spring integration, update INT_MESSAGE_GROUP got Lock wait timeout exceeded exception

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration, sometimes I got following exception:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException{failed to send Message to channel 'milestoneChannel'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE INT_MESSAGE_GROUP set UPDATED_DATE=? where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=?]; 
 Lock wait timeout exceeded;
 try restarting transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: 
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, failedMessage=GenericMessage....
```

Here is my part spring configuration file

```
  <int:channel id="milestoneChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="dataMessageStore"/>
  </int:channel>
  .....
   <si-xml:xpath-router id="messageRouter" default-output-channel="filterHistoryChannel" resolution-required="false">
  <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="//messageType"/>
  <si-xml:mapping value="MILESTONE" channel="mlestoneChannel"/>
  <si-xml:mapping value="JOB_INFO" channel="jobInfoChannel"/>
</si-xml:xpath-router>
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use a `JdbcChannelMessageStore` instead with specialized `MySqlChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store-channels. This was especially designed for `QueueChannel` operations, so you should be good.

Another, not relevant, concern: do not try to use so many `QueueChannel`s. Doesn't look like a logic of that router should start from queue. More over your `mlestoneChannel` is also `QueueChannel`. That's too much thread shifting and very stressful for default `TaskScheduler`.